# snakemake how to use glob_wilcards properly

Tags: python, wildcard, glob, snakemake

I have many paired fastq files and I have a problem on after running trim_galore package, as it named the fastq files with _1_val_1 and _2_val_2, for example:
AD50_CTGATCGTA_1_val_1.fq.gz and
AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val_2.fq.gz.

I would like continue snakemake and use

```
import os
import snakemake.io
import glob

DIR="AD50"
(SAMPLES,READS,) = glob_wildcards(DIR+"{sample}_{read}.fq.gz")
READS=["1","2"]

rule all:
    input:
        expand(DIR+"{sample}_dedup_{read}.fq.gz",sample=SAMPLES,read=READS)

rule clumpify:
    input:
        r1=DIR+"{sample}_1_val_1.fq.gz",
        r2=DIR+"{sample}_2_val_2.fq.gz"
    output:
        r1out=DIR+"{sample}_dedup_1.fq.gz",
        r2out=DIR+"{sample}_dedup_2.fq.gz"
    shell:
        "clumpify.sh in={input.r1} in2={input.r2} out={output.r1out} out2={output.r2out} dedupe subs=0"
```

and the error is:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 13 of /home/peterchung/Desktop/Rerun-Result/clumpify.smk:
Missing input files for rule clumpify:
AD50/AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val_2_val_2.fq.gz
AD50/AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val_1_val_1.fq.gz
```

I tired another way, somehow the closest is that it detected the missing input like
AD50_CTGATCGTA_1_val_2.fq.gz and AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val_1.fq.gz which is not exist.

I am not sure the glob_wildcards function I used properly since there are many underscore in it. I tired:

```
 glob_wildcards(DIR+"{sample}_{read}_val_{read}.fq.gz")
```

but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glob wildcards is effectively a wrapper for applying a regular expression to the list of directories.  By default, wildcards will match to `.*` greedily.  You need to specify your wildcards more specifically and make sure your rule input matches the same pattern matching.

Going through your example:

```
AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val_2.fq.gz
^ {sample}         ^ ^{read}
```

The `{sample}` wildcard consumes everything until the regex will no longer match, up to the val.  `{read}` is then left with just 2.

In rule all, you then request `{sample}_dedup_{read}.fq.gz`, which is `{AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val}_dedup_{2}.fq.gz` (leaving in curly braces to show where wildcards are).  When that is matched to clumpify, you request as input:
`{AD50_CTGATCGTA_2_val}_2_val_2.fq.gz`, which is why you are missing that file.

To address, you have a few options:

- If sample should contain the `1_val` part, then you need to update the input for clumpify to match your existing filenames (remove the extra `_2_val`, etc)
- If sample should only contain `AD50_CTGATCGTA`, build a more specific filename.  Consider adding [wildcard constraints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards) to limit your matches, e.g. `[\d]+` for read.  This seems to be what you are getting at in the last example.

Finally, the [expand function](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function) by default applies the product of the supplied iterables.  That's why you are getting `AD50_CTGATCGTA_1_val_2.fq.gz`, for example.  You need to add `zip` as the second argument to override that default and match the order of wildcards returned from `glob_wildcards`.  See [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-don-t-want-expand-to-use-the-product-of-every-wildcard-what-can-i-do) as well.